# Lumen loaded wrong controller when vendor directory is softlinked

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, lumen

In my example setup, I have 2 directory (each is lumen 8.x project, created by running `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/lumen lumenNUMBER`)

- ~/www/lumen1/
- ~/www/lumen2/

In my setup, webserver is apache/httpd with document root set to ~/www/

### In lumen1 project:

- file edited: routes/web.php

```php
$router->get('/route1', function () use ($router) {
    return "this is first route";
});
$router->get('/route2', function () use ($router) {
    return "this is second route";
});
$router->get("/route5", ["uses"=>"CommonController@route5"] );
```

- file added: app/Http/Controllers/CommonController.php

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class CommonController extends Controller
{
    public function route5() { "this is fifth route"; }
}
```

### In lumen2 project:

- file edited: routes/web.php

```php
$router->get('/route1', function () use ($router) {
    return "this is first route";
});
$router->get('/route2', function () use ($router) {
    return "this is second route";
});
$router->get('/route3', function () use ($router) {
    return "this is third route";
});
$router->get("/route4", ["uses"=>"SomeController@route4"] );
$router->get("/route5", ["uses"=>"CommonController@route5"] );
$router->get("/route6", ["uses"=>"CommonController@route6"] );
```

- file added: app/Http/Controllers/CommonController.php

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class CommonController extends Controller
{
    public function route5() { "this is fifth route"; }
    public function route6() { "this is sixth route"; }
}
```

- file added: app/Http/Controllers/SomeController.php

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function route4() { "this is fourth route"; }
}
```

### Problem

Everything is running fine and good, I can make such request and get expected response:

For lumen1:

- request `GET http://localhost/lumen1/public/route1` response `this is first route`
- request `GET http://localhost/lumen1/public/route2` response `this is second route`
- request `GET http://localhost/lumen1/public/route3` response error (expected): 404
- request `GET http://localhost/lumen1/public/route4` response error (expected): 404
- request `GET http://localhost/lumen1/public/route5` response `this is fifth route`
- request `GET http://localhost/lumen1/public/route6` response error (expected): 404

For lumen2:

- request `GET http://localhost/lumen2/public/route1` response `this is first route`
- request `GET http://localhost/lumen2/public/route2` response `this is second route`
- request `GET http://localhost/lumen2/public/route3` response `this is third route`
- request `GET http://localhost/lumen2/public/route4` response `this is fourth route`
- request `GET http://localhost/lumen2/public/route5` response `this is fifth route`
- request `GET http://localhost/lumen2/public/route6` response `this is sixth route`

But now I tried to get creative and deleted lumen2/vendor directory, then make symlink in lumen2/vendor to point to ../lumen1/vendor

- `ln -s ../lumen1/vendor vendor`
- output of ls -al on ~/www/lumen2:

  - `lrwxrwxrwx  1 kristian kristian     16 Apr 21 08:49 vendor -> ../lumen1/vendor`

The reason is that I'm low on disk space (this is not the only lumen project, I know it's only 40-50mb but the size is multiplied by number of project)

Now the request and their responses is (note that lumen1 is omitted since it's same with above):

- request `GET http://localhost/lumen2/public/route1` response `this is first route`
- request `GET http://localhost/lumen2/public/route2` response `this is second route`
- request `GET http://localhost/lumen2/public/route3` response `this is third route`
- request `GET http://localhost/lumen2/public/route4` response error (NOT expected): 500 Target class [App\Http\Controllers\SomeController] does not exist.
- request `GET http://localhost/lumen2/public/route5` response `this is fifth route`
- request `GET http://localhost/lumen2/public/route6` response error (NOT expected): 404

### My analysis

- closure routes do not get affected with softlinked vendor directory
- route that use softlinked vendor directory **will read it's controller from link target's controller instead of it's own**

The question is:

- why softlinked vendor directory makes lumen reads it's controller from 'lumen1' directory?
- if this approach is not feasible, then how to reduce disk space usage on lumen and/or laravel vendor directory?

Comment: That's not a good idea. If these are two seperate applications, stay on two seperate vendor folders

Comment: @NicoHaase yes I know (most different php application will need different version of dependency), but my use case is that those multiple applications are actually 1 application (single git repository) that are made into several worktrees (so the dependency will/must be identical)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I have found the problem:

I created 4 directory, each called a, b, c, d, each contains such php files:

- view.php: `<?php require_once("vendor/autoload.php"); echo "view-[x]";`
- vendor/autoload.php: `<?php require_once(dirname( __FILE__ )."/../controller.php");`
- controller.php: `<?php echo "app-[x]";` 
  In which `[x]` is replaced with directory name (so a/controller.php contains `<?php echo "app-a";` , b/controller.php contains `<?php echo "app-b";` , etc...)
- directory a is the 'master'/'main'
- directory b is copied from directory a `cp -r a b`
- directory c is copied from directory a `cp -r a c`, then I removed c/vendor and then softlink it from a's vendor directory: `cd c; ln -s ../a/vendor vendor`
- directory d is copied from directory a `cp -r a d`, then I removed d/vendor and then hardlink it from a's vendor directory: `cp -al a/vendor d/vendor`

I found out that output from:

- `GET http://localhost/a/view.php` is `app-a view-a`
- `GET http://localhost/b/view.php` is `app-b view-b`
- `GET http://localhost/c/view.php` is `app-a view-c`
- `GET http://localhost/d/view.php` is `app-d view-d`

### The solution: don't softlink, just hardlink.

This solves:

- lower disk usage compared to plainly copying vendor directory (it still consume inodes though, my laravel project have 80mb+ vendor directory, hardlinking consume about 6mb when observed via `df -h`)
- http request is served by correct controllers

### Why the trouble?

As stated by NicoHaase in comment of my question, two separate application HAVE TO stay on two seperate vendor folders.

Yes, I know, I know this and I strongly agree. But in case it's not two separate applications. It's one application inside git repository that's made into multiple directory (via git worktree). And I have an ironclad rule that when I update one branch/worktree's composer.lock/composer.json (dependency), then I have to update the others. So the goal here is to save disk space.

Why don't I just use git's checkout command then? That's because I want to be able to simultaneously work on multiple branch at same time. Stashing and/or committing unfinished changes is out of the question.

Why bother about saving disk space? When you have this much free space you will try to save disk space:

```
$ # this is the size of my vendor directory
du -sh vendor
83M     vendor
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       XXXX  XXX  413M  XXX /

$ rm -r vendor
$ # this is my free space when I deleted vendor directory
$ df -h       
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       XXXX  XXX  419M  XXX /

$ cp -r ../../myproject/vendor/ vendor
$ # this is my free space when copied vendor directory
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       XXXX  XXX  336M  XXX /

$ cp -al ../myproject/vendor/ vendor
$ # this is my free space when using hardlinked vendor directory
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       XXXX  XXX  413M  XXX /
```

### TL;DR: don't softlink, do hardlink instead

instead of `ln -s [target] [link]`, do `cp -al [target] [link]`